# change xpath code to get correct info php curl

Tags: php, xml, curl, xpath

okay so i have a script that use the following source code

```
<h4>
<label id="ct0_l00_PageContainer_MyContainer_sym" for="symbol">
%
</label>59</h4>

my xpath code is 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$value = $xpath->query('//label[@id="ct0_l00_PageContainer_MyContainer_sym"]/following-sibling::text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

this query worked fine but after changing a few bits it no longer works i have the new source code wich is below

```
<div id="ctl0_PageContainer_Container_divSummary">
                <div class="blueheaderbar">
                    <h2>
                        Summary</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="usesummary">
                    <div class="ccbody">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="greybox">
                                <div class="boxOutlineW">
                                    <span class="topLeft bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="pointbox">
                                            <h3>
                                                last 2 years</h3>
                                            <div class="boxOutlineG infoBoxwhite">
                                                <span class="topLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <h4>
                                                        98%</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="greybox">
                                <div class="boxOutlineW">
                                    <span class="topLeft bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="pointsbox">
                                            <h3>
                                                You have used</h3>
                                            <div class="boxOutlineG infoBoxwhite">
                                                <span class="topLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <h4>
                                                        91%</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="greybox">
                                <div class="boxOutlineW">
                                    <span class="topLeft bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                        <!--for IE6-->
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="pointsbox">
                                            <h3>
                                                You still have </h3>
                                            <div class="boxOutlineG infoBoxwhite">
                                                <span class="topLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <h4>
                                                        7%</h4>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

if any one could help me i need to write a xpath for this part of the source

```
                                            You still have </h3>
                                            <div class="boxOutlineG infoBoxwhite">
                                                <span class="topLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="topRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomLeft bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span><span class="bottomRight bg">
                                                    <!--for IE6-->
                                                </span>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <h4>
                                                        7%</h4>
```

can anyone help me change this so it gets the correct value of 7%

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you target the `li` which content starts with "You still have" and then select the `h4` element

This translates to this expression

```
.//li[@class="greybox"][starts-with(normalize-space(.//h3), "You still have")]//h4
```

You can additionally remove the trailing `\n` with

```
normalize-space(
    .//li[@class="greybox"][starts-with(normalize-space(.//h3), "You still have")]//h4
)
```